# How can I use one viewmodel for two composable screen in jetpack compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I have a screen called AddNutritionSearchRoute and on this screen there are foods that the user has selected, for example apple, pear, watermelon etc. There is a list button on this screen. When the user presses the list button, he goes to the screen to list the selected items called SelectedItemListRoute and here the user can delete the items he has selected, for example the apple, pear, watermelon list. Let it delete the apple and go back to the AddNutritionSearchRoute screen. When it comes to this screen again, I need to use the same list, that is, pear and watermelon must remain in the list because the apple has been deleted. It seems ridiculous to constantly move the list around, there must be an easier way. My codes are as follows

**AddNutritionSearchRoute**

```
@Composable
fun AddNutritionSearchRoute(
    navHostController: NavHostController,
    mealId:Int?,
    viewModel: AddNutritionSearchViewModel = hiltViewModel()


...
```

**AddNutritionSearchViewModel ViewModel**

```
@HiltViewModel
class AddNutritionSearchViewModel @Inject constructor(
   ...
) : ViewModel() {


    private val _selectedNtrItem = MutableStateFlow(SelectedNtrItem())
    val selectedNtrItem: StateFlow<SelectedNtrItem> = _selectedNtrItem.asStateFlow()

    fun deleteItemFromList(item: NutritionSearchItem) {
        _selectedNtrItem.value.items.remove(item)
    }

    fun addSelectedNutritionItem(
        ntrItem: NutritionSearchItem,
        selectedNtrItem: ArrayList<NutritionSearchItem>
    ) {
        if (selectedNtrItem.contains(ntrItem)) {
            selectedNtrItem.remove(ntrItem)
        } else {
            selectedNtrItem.add(ntrItem)
        }
    }
   ...
```

**SelectedItemListScreen**

If I define the viewmodel like below in this way and access the list via the viewmodel, the list appears empty. Even if I select an element, the list is probably empty because I have defined the viewmodel again.

```
@Composable
fun SelectedItemListRoute(
    navHostController: NavHostController,
    list: SelectedNtrItem?
    viewModel: AddNutritionSearchViewModel = hiltViewModel(), 
) {

    SelectedItemListScreen(navHostController,list?.items ?: arrayListOf() )
}

    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
    @Composable
    fun SelectedItemListScreen(
        navHostController: NavHostController,
        list: ArrayList<NutritionSearchItem>
    
    ) {
    
        val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    
        val modalBottomSheetState =
            rememberModalBottomSheetState(initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden)
    
        ModalBottomSheetLayout(
            sheetContent = {
                BaseBottomSheet(
                    content = {
                        DeleteItemConfirmation(
                            onConfirmClick = {
    
                                scope.launch {
                                    modalBottomSheetState.hide()
                                }
    
                            },
                            onCancelClick = {
                                scope.launch {
                                    modalBottomSheetState.hide()
                                }
                            }
                        )
                    }
                )
            },
            sheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
            sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 16.dp, topEnd = 16.dp),
        ) {
    
            Scaffold(topBar = {
                SelectedItemListTopBar(
                    onClickCancel = {
                        navHostController.popBackStack()
                    },
                    listSize = list.size
                )
            }) { padding ->
                LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.padding(15.dp)) {
                    items(list) { item ->
                        BaseNtrItem(
                            ntrId = item.nutritionId,
                            image = item.image,
                            ntrName = item.nutritionName,
                            kcal = item.kcal,
                            unit = item.unitName,
                            onClick = {}
                        ) {
                            Row() {
                                Image(
                                    modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                                        scope.launch {
                                            modalBottomSheetState.animateTo(ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded)
                                        }
                                    },
                                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_red_delete),
                                    contentDescription = ""
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Navigation :

```
...
  composable(
            route = "${ContentWidgetScreens.SelectedItemListScreen.route}/{$SELECTED_NTR_ITEM_LIST}",
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument(SELECTED_NTR_ITEM_LIST) {
                    type = ANSAssetParamType()
                }
            )
        ) {backStackEntry ->

            val selectedNtrItemList = backStackEntry.arguments?.getParcelable<SelectedNtrItem>(SELECTED_NTR_ITEM_LIST)
            SelectedItemListRoute(navHostController,selectedNtrItemList)
        }
  composable(
            route = "${ContentWidgetScreens.AddNutritionSearchScreen.route}?$MEAL_ID={$MEAL_ID}",
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument(name = MEAL_ID) {
                    type = NavType.IntType
                    defaultValue = -1
                })
          )
        { backStackEntry ->
            val mealId = backStackEntry.arguments?.getInt(MEAL_ID)
            AddNutritionSearchRoute(navHostController,mealId)
        }
...
```

Comment: Store the data in lower layers like data source, repository, etc depending on the requirement. It can then be shared with different view models.

Comment: You can also create the viewmodel instance inside Navigation file instead of SelectedItemListRoute's parameter and pass the same viewmodel to both composable. This way you can use the viewmodel as sharedViewmodel.

Comment: how can ı do that ? can you show simple example

Comment: and also I learned moving a viewmodel was not the right approach. is there a another way I can do ? more better

Comment: You don't need to move the viewmodel, essentially you need "single source of truth". Just use one View model for both destinations. In your navigation where you pass the viewmodel to your screen, just pass the same instance of the same view model to both screens. You essentially combine the two view models into one. You can pass data between screens but it's not recommended to do that with complex data as it can cause data loss. I can give you an example later tonight when I get the time if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: okey thanks I will wait for your example @WBarber

Answer (score 0):

So you can do this in your navigation in like NavHost. Just pass the ViewModel to the NavHost and from the NavHost down to screens you would like to have access to it. This way both screens will have access to the same ViewModel instance

```
fun NavHostExample(
    navController: NavHostController,
    sharedViewModel: MySharedViewModel
) {
    NavHost(navController) {
        composable( route = Screens.MainMenuScreen.route ) {
            MainScreen(
                navController = navController,
                viewModel = sharedViewModel // passing the ViewModel to first screen
            )
        }

        composable( route = Screens.Settings.route ) {
            SettingsScreen(
                navController = navController,
                viewModel = sharedViewModel // passing same ViewModel instance to second screen
            )
        }
    }
}
```

And just initialize your ViewModel and pass it to your NavHost wherever you may have that:

```
// Initialise
val sharedViewModel = MySharedViewModel()

// Pass to nav controller, and we have it setup to pass to views
NavHostExample(
    navController = navController,
    sharedViewModel = sharedViewModel
)
```

This way we aren't passing complex data through navigation but rather a pointer to our SharedViewModel that both screens now have access to making the SharedViewModel our DataLayer